# All project files have disappeared after installing a cocoapod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I just installed `GSMessages` `cocoapod` and just after, i tried opening my workspace, it just says its disappeared. I've opened it but all the files are missing/gone. I have no idea why they would disappear. I haven't had this problem before when installing all the other `cocoapods`. Does anyone have any idea how i can recover all my files again in the workspace. 
[image]

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini i didn't, i just installed a cocoapod and tried reopening the workspace, all files were gone

Comment: It was only the project on git not the pods